# Loop over SQLCMD results on batch file

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sqlcmd

I'm using the folling .cmd to get the values returned by one sql sentence.

```
@echo off
SET SERVER=.\SQLExpress 
SET SQLCMD="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd.exe"
for %%f in (%SQLCMD%) do set alternatepath=%%~sf

SET EXEC_LINE=%alternatepath% -S %SERVER% -d SkpMaster -h-1 -Q "set nocount on; select distinct id from sometable "

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`%EXEC_LINE%`) do (
    set count=%%i
    echo %count%
)

if not defined count (
    echo Failed to execute SQL statement 1>&2
)
```

The SQL return 4 occurrences, but the echo print 4 times the 1º ocurrence.

Maybe I'm not using correctly the "delims=" option, I have also tested with "tokens=*" with the same result.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed after handle the parameter %%i in a different way.

```
@echo off
SET SERVER=.\SQLExpress 
SET SQLCMD="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd.exe"
for %%f in (%SQLCMD%) do set alternatepath=%%~sf

SET EXEC_LINE=%alternatepath% -S %SERVER% -d SkpMaster -h-1 -Q "set nocount on; select distinct id from sometable "

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`%EXEC_LINE%`) do call :processline %%i

if not defined count (
    echo Failed to execute SQL statement 1>&2
)

pause
goto :eof

:processline
echo line=%*
goto :eof

:eof
```